# Can the melting temperature of metals be altered by modifying the local electric charge?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, solid-state-physics, temperature, charge

I'm researching a project in which metal needs to be melted.  It would be very helpful to be able to reduce the melting temperature to improve the feasibility of the project.  I've been looking into the possibility of lowering the melting point using nano-particles and the phenomenon of melting point depression.  Alternatively, would a metal's melting point be altered by depleting the electrons in the area being melted?  For instance, would the positive side of a  parallel-plate capacitor have a different melting temperature than that of the negative side?  If there is any such phenomenon, would it require an impractically high potential electric field to create a significant change?

Comment: Do you realize that having any kind of hot liquid carry enough electric charge that it overcomes the surface tension is kind of a bad idea? Like, molten-iron-everywhere kind of bad?

Comment: Depleting the number of electrons in a metal by a tiny amount corresponding to an average of even a billionth of an electron per nucleus would be a pretty impractically large electrical charge for a parallel plate capacitor or any sizable piece of metal, I'm sure. Try doing a quick back-of-the-envelope calculation yourself. Just doesn't seem like a viable idea according to my sniff test.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback and I can certainly appreciate the concern in regards to molten metal with a significant charge.  Just to be clear, I'm not looking to melt some large bulk metal object.  I am looking to reach a sintering temperature of a very thin layer of metal in powder form (roughly 25-50 microns thick).   It looks like this may not be a viable option but  I will look more closely at the numbers.  Setting aside the practicality of obtaining the required charge,  would depleting the valence electrons cause a change to the melting temperature?